# CAB Framework WorkItem event switching between user controls

Tags: c#, wcf, user-controls, datacontract, cab

I have a problem using CAB Framework. I created some GUI User control interfaces and put them on my screen, that works fine. However, I would like to save my data between the different user controls. I made some DataContracts using WCF and I put the data I need in the DataContract and put those in properties so they're accessible from the WorkItem. Now I used the following function in the WorkItem to process the data:

```
protected override void OnWorkItemSmartPartChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        MessageBox.Show(_testWorkItemControlAdres.AdresContract.Gemeente);
    }
```

When I change between user controls, I want to see if it can succesfully access the data. However, when I switch between the wizard steps (the user controls) it never triggers the event. Do I need to add this event somewhere else or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually link the event to the WorkItem?

Workspace.SmartPartActivated += new EventHandler(OnWorkItemSmartPartChanged);

Cheers